# Duplicated value in ng-select when reopening modal - Angular

Tags: angular

Lets consider we have 3 states in our Database.

1. Florida
2. Texas
3. Montana

I have a button called <kbd>Create Template</kbd>. When I click on it, a panel is opened on right side of browser. On `ngOnInit()` of that panel, I find states from backend and display all of them using this code.

**create-template-types.component.html**

```html
<ng-select
  formControlName="state"
>
  <ng-option
    *ngFor="let state of states"
    [value]="state?.name"
    >{{ state?.name }}
  </ng-option>
</ng-select>
```

**create-template-types.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.stateSubscription = this.locationService
      .findAllStates()
      .subscribe((states: State[]) => {
        this.states = states;
        this.states?.sort((s1, s2) => (s1?.name < s2?.name ? -1 : 1));
        this.states.unshift({ code: 'ALL', name: 'All' });
      });
  }

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.stateSubscription?.unsubscribe();
}
```

If I open the modal once, it shows this which is correct and expected.

1. All
2. Florida
3. Montana
4. Texas

But if I close and open the modal again(without refreshing the page), it shows **All** 2 times.

1. All
2. All
3. Florida
4. Montana
5. Texas

Similarly, if I close and open the modal again, **All** is shown 3 times. I want to know why is this happening because `this.states` is assigned everytime `stateSubscription` is called.

---

I tried:

Cleared the `this.states` array before assigning new values to it. Added `this.states = [];` at the beginning of the `ngOnInit` method. But it does not work. It would be great if someone can help with this. Thanks in advance

**Edit:**

I tried to put a debug pointer. When I open the modal, `this.states` is always empty. Then,why **ALL** is added twice or thrice ?

[image]

Comment: what's inside `this.locationService.findAllStates()` ? a simple HTTP request?
please show some code or add `.tap(states => console.log('got states', states))` to see what you get

Comment: You could try and debug how often the block inside `subscribe`  is executed (and also the states that `findAllStates()` is returning).

Comment: You can debug by a breakpoint or a simple console log. to check how often the findAllStates is triggered

Comment: @Zerotwelve Check out the code here: https://codeshare.io/0gDPWm

Comment: @GeoDev @Cuzy I tried that, findAllStates() gets executed everytime I open the modal. But that is expected. findAllStates returns the 3 states that are mentioned in question. Those 3 states are not duplicated. Only `All` is duplicated

Comment: It is good to be aware of mutable (arrays) and immutable.  So (deep) copy the array, like  @julian shows you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably locationService is emitting the array with the same reference at every subscription. Meaning that at the first execution, "All" is added on the source array.

One good way to avoid this is to create a copy. One way of doing it is by using the spread operator on the source array.

```
this.stateSubscription = this.locationService
  .findAllStates()
  .subscribe((states: State[]) => {
    this.states = [
      { code: "ALL", name: "All" },
      ...states.sort((s1, s2) => (s1?.name < s2?.name ? -1 : 1)),
    ];
  });
```

Comment: That kind of makes sense. But can you help me understand why other states did not come twice(Florida, Texas and Montana) if locationService is emitting the array with the same reference at every subscription.

Comment: I assume the other state didn't come twice because they are not inserted twice. They are inserted once initially in the service. But on each subscribe, "All" is inserted in the original array here.

Comment: Your solution works but may be this is not the reason that you have mentioned. Check [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGECcFMEMBdqlgO2ZSsCeoD2AzPAIwCtoBjeAZwCgBLFRSfWcpABWkitzQG8aoUClgBbaAC5QVeJAYBzANyDk8ycICuool2UBfGjQBusSKAAO0XOYA26zt14BtALqgAvKCcq+wseoAiAClcAAsUAIAaVXUAJgBWUD1Inz9xKWDUaCiYqQBmAAYklKFfEXTQAIBBGzo2HNg1KViADmKaF2Uacl4eOwA6G1x5AApLazsAShpx22h+jRQqULp8eBGy-ykAciqAGT3t6Mb1AEYCor1J5R6l3AGh0dmpwxMzZ-suHhRXDy9U8qBELhWINJqgBLtUppIFZUHHcGFKGgTYVaq1Njw3IQtrJDpdW59eaPMZWObTD4LJYrNYbGE7faHBFnC5Ja7dXr3YnDUkTaCTIA)

Comment: The snippet you send does not represent what is happening here. On the snippet, you are changing the reference of the source array (l17, new reference is created)
Currently in your code, the original array is constructed once with Florida, Texas and Montana, and stored in reference #REF. 
On each subscribe, the same #REF is emitted, and on each subscribe, "All" is added to the #REF. The array is not constructed again, it is only emitted, therefore no additional Florida

Comment: [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=3#code/PTAEGECcFMEMBdqlgO2ZSsCeoD2AzPAIwCtoBjeAZwCgBLFRSfWcpABWkitzQG8aoUClgBbaAC5QVeJAYBzANyDk8ycICuool2UBfGjQBusSKAAO0XOYA26zt14BtALqgAvKCcq+wseoAiAClcAAsUAIAaVXUAJgBWUD1Inz9xKWDUaCiYqQBmAAYklKFfEXTQAIBBGzo2HNg1KViADmKaF2Uacl4eOwA6G1x5AApLazsAShpx22h+jRQqULp8eBGy-ykAciqAGT3t6Mb1AEYCor1J5R6l3AGh0dmpwxMzZ+hYjwsrOa7bvrzR5jX52WLTD6xBZLFZrDZpdS7A5HXKgc6Xa7dXr3IHDEETT6TIA) represents your issue

Comment: This link opens the same link that I shared, may be its mistaken. Can you please update the link

Comment: The difference is on line17

Comment: If on each subscribe, "All" is added to the #REF, then we should be able to see ALL in `this.states` when we opened the modal second time. But `this.states` is empty array when open the modal second time. Please refer the screenshot added in the questions

Comment: `this` refer to the component. The component is created and destroyed every time you open/close the modal. 
Therefore this.states will be empty array until it gets affected by #REF again.
Try to `console.log(states)` and `console.log(this.states)` in the subscribe, you will understand

Comment: Doing this helped me understand better, thanks for being responsive ! I will accept the answer after running some tests and everything